# Liquid syntax errror shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm getting this error while trying to edit some scss in `theme.scss.liquid`

> Liquid syntax error (line 750): Variable '{{ "ico-select.svg" |
> asset_url }' was not properly terminated with regexp: /}}/

Here's the line 750 error:

```
/*================ SVG ================*/
$svg-select-icon: #{'{{ "ico-select.svg" | asset_url }
}

'};
```

Comment: Did you first try to delete blank line?
$svg-select-icon: #{'{{ "ico-select.svg" | asset_url }}'};

Then not sure what you are trying to achieve with this var. Why the "{ }" around Liquid string, looks like syntax error at first sight? 

Would you provide more info about how you plan to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code format is like [this](https://prnt.sc/ug0teb).

But according to shopify syntax, it would be like [this](https://prnt.sc/ug0z4z).